# Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined with getelementByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

i have button with class but doesn't have Id,
[this is Button Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puOG0.png)
,i want to any sound when i click that button so i called it by getElementsByClassName and added this function

```
var stopMusicExt = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-control-button-next slide-lockable")[0];
stopMusicExt.onclick = function() {
this.pause();
this.currentTime = 0;
}
```

but every time browser show this error

---

### Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

---

what can i do to solve this problem.please?

Comment: Where in the page is the script located?  Is it directly on the window or is it in an onload function?

Answer (score 2):

Also, don't use event properties! Use addEventListener ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) as a modern standard instead:

```
var stopMusicExt = document.getElementsByClassName("btn cs-button inflexible slide-control-button-next slide-lockable")[0];

stopMusicExt.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.pause();
  this.currentTime = 0;
});
```

---

To be explicit, you may add an `id` attribute to your button element:

```
<button id="myButton" class="dtn cs-button inflexible etc">
```

and use `getElementById()` method to access it

```
var stopMusicExt = document.getElementById("myButton");
```

Comment: i tried this 

`var stopMusicExt = document.getElementsByClassName(".button.btn.cs-button.inflexible.slide-control-button-next.slide-lockable")[0];
console.log(stopMusicExt);`

but it show to me that the classname is undefined

Comment: @beko Due to [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) "class names are separated by whitespace", no dots are needed, sorry for confusing! I also updated the answer and added `id`-based variant.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector seems to not have found the class names you were looking for, hence why the `onclick` handler wasn't bound to the element you wanted. Take a look at the example below:

```js
var stopMusicExt = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-control-button-next slide-lockable")[0];
stopMusicExt.onclick = function() {
  alert('clicked');
}
```

```css
.slide-control-button-next {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-control-button-next slide-lockable">

</div>
```

Comment: yes you are right, 

the problem in my code is that the classname is undefined, but how it isn't undefined and i use it without any change in class name ?